# How do i optimize android application?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am making a android application not using complicated task but using ui controlling.
But, i saw the log of the android monitor of android studio.
It says something '41 frames below, warning blah blah...'

I want to extract the code from main thread(ui thread) to another thread...
but, the code i wrote was just used ui controll(like `updatelocationlistener`,  `AlertDialog.Builder dialog.... show()`, `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id....)`...

My one activity code line is >300 lines. I think it is too big... So I want separate code diffused, so is this the reason ? (low performance)
I think i use a thread maybe

so i thought `runonuithread`.. but
I read the guide, and `runonuithread` is just sending the runnable.
of course, the runnable sent is executed by main thread(ui thread).
so there is not reason to use `runonuithread` ? why people use this ?

Comment: may be you are doing huge operations on `mainThread`

Comment: You can maybe use a memory monitor to check where the leak is happening, and start optimizing from there.

Comment: @pamobo0609 Do android studio provide the code execution time monitor?

Comment: **Lint** should help you with code the optimization. This is supported in both Eclipse and Android Studio IDEs. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html

Comment: @fasdgoc yes it does. There is several options available in android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why people use this ?

It is used when lets assume you have a background task running and you want to update the layout then you call `runonuithread` method, since we can only update the layout on Main thread so we use this method.

That is only one use I told to explain a little.

Comment: But does `run` in runonuithread code executed by uithread? What difference is runonuithread and just write the code directly e.g onCreate

Comment: @fasdgoc: read his answer few more times. (yes, it runs on uithread, no difference. Why? Sometimes you want to do for example `TextView.setText(...)` from background thread, that's not allowed, so you post `Runnable` with `setText` on uithread.)

Comment: @fasdgoc `runonuithread` is tiny fraction slower, as the posting and inter-thread communication is involved. If you are already in the ui thread, running the code directly is not wasting time with `Runnable`/`post` overhead. When you are in background thread, you have no other option anyway (how to update UI views). If your app is spending time mostly on UI calls, then you can't move it to background thread, you should redesign your views usage, to call less. For example calling `findViewById` per update is code smell, you can probably cache that, etc blah blah blah.